# AWS Package for AdMob Like Site

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on something similar to AdMob and was planning to use Amazon Web Services this time. I would like to use EC2 instance running Linux on it.

What do you think a AdMob like site has utilization for a month and what's the best configured instance for it be?

It would use HTTPS for which I have already bought SSL certificate. I am more concerned about utilization and data transfer in and out. Is there a way to calculate usage per user?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really open, but I have a solution :

Look at the AWS Architecture Center :

http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/

There are plenty of typical architecture.

You have an adserving architecture here :

http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_adserving_06.pdf

Hope this will help you.

[To calculate usage per user, it's not easy. You can save all your user's actions, and public actions, but it will cost you usage costs. The best way is to evaluate it for the next months, with last months datas.]